# Computed property in a v-loop workaround

Tags: javascript, vue.js, computed-properties

I'm trying to make the code below work knowing that computed properties can't take parameters. Do you have any idea ? I'm exploring the use of watchers on functions but I was wondering if there was not an easier solution to do this.

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
      return {
        sessions: {
          "156": {
            tickets: {
              "01": {
                available: true,
              },
              "02": {
                available: false,
              },
            }
          },
        },
        tickets: {
          "01": {
            attr: "somestring",
          },
          "02": {
            attr: "someotherstring",
          },
        },
      },
    };
  },
  computed: {
    sessionTickets(session) {
        let _this = this;
        let sessionTickets = {};
        $.each(_this.session.tickets, function(ticketId, sessionTicket) {
            if(sessionTicket.available) {
                sessionTickets[ticketId] = _this.tickets[ticketId];
            }
        });
        return sessionTickets;
    },
  },
});

<div v-for="session in sessions">
  <div v-for="sessionTicket in sessionTickets(session)">
    {{ sessionTicket.attr }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to "WallOp" for making me realize that my computed property is in a sessions loop and so it can normally become a class method and be refreshed on sessions refresh !

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use computed property. Just filter tickets of sessions. Like this:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      sessions: {
        "156": {
          tickets: {
            "01": {
              available: true,
            },
            "02": {
              available: false,
            },
          }
        },
      },
      tickets: {
        "01": {
          attr: "somestring",
        },
        "02": {
          attr: "someotherstring",
        },
      },
    },
  };
  computed: {
    filteredSessions() {
      return this.sessions.map( session => {
        let tickets = {};
        for(key in session.tickets) {
          if(session.tickets[key].available && this.tickets.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            tickets[key] = this.tickets[key];
          }
        }
        session.tickets = tickets;

        return session;
      });
    },
  },
});

<div v-for="session in filteredSessions">
  <div v-for="ticket in session.tickets">
    {{ ticket.attr }}
  </div>
</div>
```